# I sound like a robot when using a Bluetooth headset

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth, wireless-headset

When I use a Bluetooth headset with Windows 10, I sound like a robot with an 8-bit voice.

I tried all combinations of these devices, always the same result:

- Bose QuietControl 30
- AKG N60NC Wireless
- Lenovo ThinkPad T480s (Windows 10.0.18363.1198)
- Windows 10 desktop with a generic Bluetooth adapter

If I use the very same headsets with my OnePlus 6T everything is fine and the transmitted voice is high quality.

Since this issue happens with multiple devices and different combinations of them, there must be something wrong with the Windows Settings.

Does anyone have an idea what to do?

Comment: +1 just for the best opening line of a question

Answer (score 1):

In the 'classic' Sound control panel application, make sure your device is set as Headphones rather than Headset.

[image]

If I use my AKG Y50BT's in Headset mode, I sound like a robot and the incoming call quality if also poor. I disabled 'Headset' mode.

Comment: If I use it as a headphone, then I cannot use the mic, right?

Comment: Nope. My mic works just fine when in Headphones, but I don't like it as I can't hear my own voice properly (weird, I know).

Comment: @Hannes how did you get on?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Following this advice, my notebook starts using its built-in microphone.