# Wireless earbuds (Oppo enco X) sound terrible with distortions only on my primary Windows 10 machine

Tags: windows-10, audio, bluetooth, headset, wireless-headset

The wireless earbuds in question is connected to my primary Windows 10 machine using Bluetooth and sounds Terrible. I can hardly make out anything from the sound. I have a Gigabyte B450 Wifi Motherboard with bluetooth 4.0 support and the earbuds support bluetooth 5.2.

What I have done and confirmed so far

- I have tested the wireless earbuds on android devices and other WINDOWS 10 Machines and it worked fine.
- I have tested other bluetooth audio devices like Bluetooth speakers on the problematic Windows 10 machine and they sounded just fine too.
- I have uninstalled and reinstalled drivers and disabled/reenabled on device manager.
- Windows bluetooth and Audio troubleshooter
- Removed audio device from PC and paired it again.

Is there anything else that I should try?

EDIT: I just noticed that if I sit SUPER close to the PC, like almost touching it, then the sound comes out fine. If I take even a step back it gets out all distorted. I'm wondering if its an onboard bluetooth module related issue. But if it is indeed a hardware problem, It doesn't make sense why other Bluetooth audio devices work just fine even at large distances.

Comment: Check out my answer on https://superuser.com/questions/1604368/i-sound-like-a-robot-when-using-a-bluetooth-headset/1604371#1604371

Comment: If @spikey_richie's answer doesn't help, you may want to rule out whether it's the BT radio in the earbuds, the BT radio on the PC, or interference _(BT uses ~2.4GHz spectrum IIRC - fact check that to be sure)_. To rule out the first two, try different BT ear buds/headphones, and to rule out interference, if it's a laptop, move it around the house, but if it's a PC, ensure it's not within ~30' of any electronics that use the same spectrum, including refrigerators and other appliances that use >220V; if it is, turn off those electronics/flip the breaker off momentarily to check for improvement

Comment: @JW0914 Refrigerators and other appliances that use >220V typically use 50 Hz or 60 Hz, not 2.4 GHz. The latter *is* used by microwave ovens when they're operating.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I'm aware of that, thank you. The higher voltage and amperage used by appliances can cause EMF interference with WiFi signals depending on where they're located relative to the client and host, and is why it should be checked by simply switching their breaker(s) off, verifying if it results in any improvement, then flipping the breakers back on; due to this not being as common as the former, it's why it was listed last.

Comment: USB 3 is known to be capable of interfering with devices using 2.4 GHz ([Intel white paper](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/docs/io/universal-serial-bus/usb3-frequency-interference-paper.html)). Can you move the Bluetooth antenna away from any USB 3 devices?

Comment: Thank you all so much for helping me troubleshoot the issue. I have posted the answer that worked for me. The damaged antenna wires ended up being the cause of the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue in my case was the WIFI+Bluetooth Antenna that came included with the Gigabyte B450 Wifi Pro motherboard which had bluetooth chipset on board. The wires have been damaged, I replaced it and everything works fine now.